# I need same python command in php

Tags: python, php, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I have python code which is sending curl Request to Huawei USG Device , this code can receive information without any problem , but as my project is php project so I tried to send Curl request to Same Huawei USG but I get this error

> error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

I think this problem is for TLSV1_3 , I need to prevent code from sending it as Hello packet .
this is the pythin command which is doing this task , (Prevent TLSV1_3)

```
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSV1_3
```

the ClientHello don’t contain "Supported Version: TLS1.3
I need same command for php , how can I do that in php , because if I removed that line from code , I get the same error that I get in php code

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to force a specific SSL/TLS version by using the `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` Curl option. Unlike the Python implementation, I don't think it's possible to *exclude* a particular version, but if you know that **TLS 1.2** will work, you can force it with:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
// ...
```

The values available are listed next to the `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` block here on the [`curl_setopt` manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> One of CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT (0), CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 (1), CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2 (2), CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3 (3), CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0 (4), CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 (5) or CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 (6).
>
> **Note:**
>
> Your best bet is to not set this and let it use the default. Setting it to 2 or 3 is very dangerous given the known vulnerabilities in SSLv2 and SSLv3.

Comment: thank you for your reply  I tried all version , but still have same problem , what  making me crazy , is  I tried same php code in another ubuntu machine it is working , and tried it on 3'rd ubuntu machine not working , then tried with 4'th ubuntu machine  it is working , so the php code working on some machines but not working on some